# Auto Deleting specific characters from text file and saving to a new location using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for some help with this, Basically I'm trying to perform 3 actions with powershell (if all are possible)

- Auto run the following on a file that is saved to a specific folder
- Delete Characters from that file
- Save the file to a new location

I started by putting together the code to remove the characters and it works (in so much as powershell ISE displays the text with the characters removed but when outputting the file it empty.

Once the new file is created it would be great if it could move to another folder and delete the previous file.

Here's what I have so far.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\Test\import.txt

foreach ($line in (Get-Content C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\Test\import.txt)) 
{ $line -replace "\&", "" -replace "\£", "" -replace "\+", "" -replace "\-",  "" -replace "\)","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\$","" -replace "\#","" -replace "\*","" -replace "\%",""} 
Out-File -Encoding UTF8 import.new.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all the lines in one hit without having to use a `Foreach` statement, by piping your replaced content straight into the `Out-File` Cmdlet.

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\Test\import.txt"
$newfile = "C:\YourNewLocation\import.new.txt"
$content -replace "\&", "" -replace "\£", "" -replace "\+", "" -replace "\-",  ""`
         -replace "\)","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\$","" -replace "\#","" `
         -replace "\*","" -replace "\%","" | Out-File -FilePath $newfile -Encoding UTF8
```

The code above with create a new file with replaced strings, in a new location and leave the original file alone. If you what the original file to be removed after use the `Remove-Item` Cmdlet.

As for Auto running when a file is saved to the folder, I would look into having a `Scheduled Task` running every X minutes that runs the script. Ether that or you will need a script running constantly that polls the folder for changes.

Comment: @CraigCarter Can you accept the answer if it has answered your question.